# Proper Construct for Primefaces Dialog

Tags: primefaces

I am getting confused on the constrcut of a Primefaces 3 dialog.

I see question in SO that has this pattern.  The form is outside the dialog.

```
<h:form>
  <p:dialog id="dialog" modal="true" widgetVar="dlg">
  </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

But other question has this.

```
<p:dialog id="dialog" modal="true" widgetVar="dlg">
    <h:form>      
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

The Primefaces showcase http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogLogin.jsf favors the latter one.

I am getting confused if there's any valid reason for using the one over the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You always better use place the `<h:form>` inside `<p:dialog` like this

```
<p:dialog id="dialog" modal="true" widgetVar="dlg">
    <h:form>      
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

cause you dialog content might be "taken" out from your page and appended some where else in your DOM tree , so if you place the dialog inside some form, it can cause your dialog to be *relocated somewhere else* and to cause all your buttons/links and other elements to stop working (this is a very common question here in SO)

So in order to be allays on the safe side place you `<h:form>` tag inside your `<p:dialog` tag

Another example is when you use `appendToBody="true"` in dialog  :

> if dialog is inside an h:form component and appendToBody is enabled, on the browser
>   dialog would be outside of form and may cause unexpected results. In this case, nest a form inside
>   a dialog.