# p:dialog not appearing after commandButton oncomplete

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am facing a strange issue and I am not able to find the cause.
I have a dataGrid in which I placed a commandButton.

```
<p:dataGrid paginator="true"
    value="#{bean.searchedSystem}" var="searchedSystemObj"  
    columns="1" rows="6"
    WidgetVar="CadModel" pageLinks="5" filteredValue="" >

<p:commandButton value="More Details..."
    action="#{bean.viewMoreDetails(searchedSystemObj)}"
    oncompleted="PF('testDialog').show()"/>
```

On action the bean is called, but it doesn't seem like the oncomplete is getting invoked.

```
<p:dialog header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="testDialog"
    modal="true" height="600" width="900">
```

All these are in a single form.
 Any idea why ?

**Solved:**
I have solved this issue. Thank you guys for helping me.
The problem was due to the "processing image..."(like a please wait while processing stuff).. It was not processed properly for each action. So i fixed it and then the dialog box started to appear.

Comment: Did you try debugging ii to help narrow down the source of the problem (e.g: try oncomplete='alert("done")' and see if that works)?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Yes ! Solved it. Pls see my update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first idea is that the attribute is `oncomplete` and not `oncompleted`.

Also, you have to take care of lowercase/uppercase problems, as JSF is XML, which is case-sensitive. I see a `WidgetVar` in your code but the correct attribute is `widgetVar`.

---

> All these are in a single form.

Then my second idea is to put a `<h:form>` inside the `<p:dialog>` and make sure you don't nest forms.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10579708/1528942 for a rational.

Comment: the higher case WidgetVar is for dataGrid, but the problem is onclick commandButton a specified action should be performed and oncomplete the dialog should appear, but in my case the dialog is not appearing

Comment: Ok I edited my answer to give you another idea. :) Do you get any error in the browser's console?